# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

i have a django rest api with jwt auth , and i have my front end with react js , i have my login function set up like this :

```
class SessionApi {
static login(data) {

const endpoint = 'http://foody-dev-dev.eu-west- 
3.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/auth/jwt/'
const csrfToken = cookie.load('csrftoken')
let lookupOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,

      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),

  }

return fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions).then(response => {
 return response.json();
}).catch(error => {
  return error;
 });
 }
}
```

and i have my load Meals function set up like this :

```
loadProducts(){
  const endpoint = 'http://foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/meals/'
  const csrfToken = cookie.load('csrftoken')
  let thisComp = this
  let token = sessionStorage.token
  let lookupOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'AUTHORIZATION': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.token}`,
          'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken


      },
  }

  fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
  .then(function(response){
      return response.json()
  }).then(function(responseData){
      console.log(responseData)
       thisComp.setState({
              products: responseData
          })

      console.log("Token Stored in meal", token)
  }).catch(function(error){
      console.log("error", error)
  })
}
```

i succes to login and to get my token but when i try to go to my Products view in react js and run the load meals function i get this error :

```
    Exception Type: TypeError at /api/meals/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or 
a number, not 'AnonymousUser'
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: No POST data

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data

META:
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/json'
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/var/www/html'
CONTEXT_PREFIX = ''
DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/var/www/html'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_HOST = 'foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com'
HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://foody-react.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com'
HTTP_REFERER = 'http://foody-react.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN = 'undefined'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = '141.226.122.202'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT = '80'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'http'
PATH_INFO = '/api/meals/'
PATH_TRANSLATED = '/opt/python/current/app/api/wsgi.py/api/meals/'
QUERY_STRING = ''
REMOTE_ADDR = '172.31.16.55'
REMOTE_PORT = '25104'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'GET'
REQUEST_SCHEME = 'http'
REQUEST_URI = '/api/meals/'
SCRIPT_FILENAME = '/opt/python/current/app/api/wsgi.py'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_ADDR = '172.31.36.251'
SERVER_ADMIN = 'root@localhost'
SERVER_NAME = 'foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com'
SERVER_PORT = '80'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SIGNATURE = ''
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5'
mod_wsgi.application_group = 'ip-172-31-36-251.eu-west-3.compute.internal|'
mod_wsgi.callable_object = 'application'
mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile = '0'
mod_wsgi.handler_script = ''
mod_wsgi.input_chunked = '0'
mod_wsgi.listener_host = ''
mod_wsgi.listener_port = '80'
mod_wsgi.process_group = 'wsgi'
mod_wsgi.queue_start = '1530048823861583'
mod_wsgi.request_handler = 'wsgi-script'
mod_wsgi.script_reloading = '1'
mod_wsgi.version = '(3, 5)'
wsgi.errors = <_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fc68ffcc030>
wsgi.multiprocess = True
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'

Settings:
Using settings module api.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = []
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '//foody-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'foody-delivery.herokuapp.com', '.herokuapp.com', 'www.velty.fr', 'www.velty.fr.herokudns.com', 'foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com']
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '********************'
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_HEADERS = {'Expires': 'Sunday, 26 August 2018 20:00:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=5270400'}
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '********************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'foody-dev'
BASE_DIR = '/opt/python/current/app'
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_HEADERS = "('Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization', 'AUTHORIZATION', 'X-Requested-With', 'credentials')"
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = "('*', 'your-domain.com', 'your-bucket-here.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com', 'foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com')"
CORS_URLS_REGEX = '^/api.*'
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': '/opt/python/current/app/db.sqlite3', 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500, 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'api.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'storages', 'corsheaders', 'rest_framework', 'rest_auth', 'foody']
INTERNAL_IPS = []
JWT_AUTH = {'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler', 'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler', 'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler', 'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER': 'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler', 'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'api.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler', 'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True, 'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(7), 'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT', 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None}
LANGUAGES = [('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ('ast', 'Asturian'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('be', 'Belarusian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('br', 'Breton'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-au', 'Australian English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('ia', 'Interlingua'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('io', 'Ido'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kab', 'Kabyle'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('mr', 'Marathi'), ('my', 'Burmese'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('os', 'Ossetic'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('udm', 'Udmurt'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOGGING = {}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = '//foody-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '//foody-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
REST_FRAMEWORK = {'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication'), 'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ()}
ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
S3_URL = '//foody-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'api.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/opt/python/current/app/staticfiles']
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'api.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/python/current/staticfiles/static-cdn-local/../www'
STATIC_URL = '//foody-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 

    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
    TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
    THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
    TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
    TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
    USE_ETAGS = False
    USE_I18N = True
    USE_L10N = True
    USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
    USE_TZ = True
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
    USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'
    X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
    YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
```

My backend looks like this :

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/auth/jwt/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path('api/auth/jwt/refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    path('api/meals/', include('foody.urls'))
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for api project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!



SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY','qj$in1cz)+2e#kc14q(6@0dx&jjq0wn$77u08!ncdq%-knz0y0')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1','foody-delivery.herokuapp.com','.herokuapp.com', 'www.velty.fr','www.velty.fr.herokudns.com','foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'storages',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',

    'foody',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'api.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'api.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "AKIAIL3JMMDWLIYBOYMA"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "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"

if 'RDS_DB_NAME' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# add this
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles', 'static-cdn-local','..', 'www')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join((BASE_DIR) ,'staticfiles', 'media-root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api.*'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    "Content-Type",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Authorization",
    "AUTHORIZATION",
    "X-Requested-With",
    "credentials"
)
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    '*',
    'your-domain.com',
    'your-bucket-here.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    'foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com'


)

from api.restconf.main import *
from api.aws.conf import *
```

views.py :

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions

from .serializers import MealSerializer
from .models import Meal
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication




class MealDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset            = Meal.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = MealSerializer
    lookup_field        = 'id'
    permission_classes  = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]





class MealListCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset            = Meal.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = MealSerializer
    permission_classes  = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]



    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        qs = Meal.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by("-id")

        query = request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=query, description__icontains=query)
        return qs



    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: That really looks like an error on the backend.

Comment: i updated my post and upload the backend code

Comment: Try in your `loadProducts` function adding `credentials: include` ib `lookupOptions` of `fetch` api

Comment: Please add also the view that handles api/meals/

Comment: @GabrielMuj i just added the views.py

Comment: @YusefBH i am now getting this error Failed to load http://foody-dev-dev.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/meals/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://foody-react.s3-website.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Let's see also the permission class `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`